# Problem for filtering sequences array to remove duplicates with shifted sequences

Tags: bash, sort, array

I had some trouble to do an array of lists comparison to remove duplicates. 
My array is composed of sequences of ternary values like this:

```
{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1}  
{0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2}  
{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0}  
{0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1}  
{0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}    
{0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0}  
{0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}  
{0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2}  
{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2}  
{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0}  
{1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1}  
{1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2}  
{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}  
{1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}  
{1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2}  
{1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0}  
{1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}  
{2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1}
```

I tried with a while loop to find duplicates with the help of a subscript testsequence.sh which is a Mathematica script wrapper to identify if two sequences are the same:

```
{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1}  
{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0}
```

These two are the same with a shift to left; my subscript returns 1 in that case and the subscript is used like that:

```
./testsequence.sh "`echo ${foundsequence[0]}`" "`echo ${foundsequence[1]}`"
```

My first try with the while loop compared only the first sequence to others, removing only half of the duplicates.

The good result must be:

```
{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1}  
{0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2}
```

As they are the only two unique sequences in the list.

Be aware that sequences in the array are not of a fixed length . They could vary from 2 to 121 or even more in length . That's why i want to keep my subscripts to compare two row of the array .

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what your question is: are you just asking how to loop over all distinct pairs of elements of a bash array? If so, you probably want a nested for loop - something like `for((i=0;i<$((n-1));i++)); do for((j=$((i+1));j<$n;j++)); do <somecommand> "${foundsequence[$i]}" "${foundsequence[$j]}"; done; done` where `n=${#foundsequence[@]}`

Comment: Hello the goal is to obtain only uniq sequences in the list at the end ,  same sequence may be shifted or not , and push these uniq sequence in a second array which contain only the filtered sequences . Here for this example i got 26 sequences and i must obtain in the second array the two distinct sequences i found manually . Thanks for the proposition i will try that with my scripts .

Comment: Riiight - but if I'm reading it correctly, you already have a Mathematica script that tests a *pair* of sequences to see if they are cyclic permutations of one another - do you want to replace that script entirely, or merely feed it with pairs of sequences from the array?

Comment: I don't want to replace it , because it works for every size of sequence per array offset , sequence could be as long as 121 ternary values , my entire set of scritps calculates modulo 3 reduction of integer sequences from every type of sequence (fibonacci , perrin , padovan , tribonacci , tetranacci ,pentanacci and others) to find all the periodic sequences in ternary values associated. for example for a a(n)=a(n-3)+a(n-4)+a(n-5) sequence (called tripentanacci) periodic modulo3 sequence vary from 2 to 55(which are also fibonacci values) in length for every inititalisation values

Comment: The example shown above is for padovan sequence , there are 26 generated periodic sequence which have shifted duplicates leading to two uniq sequences . For Fibonacci it's eight leading to  only one after filtering ( the Pisano sequence : 01120221 ) .

Comment: If you want more explanation of my goal : https://oeis.org/A275778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bash loop that reads input from a file named 'input' into an array named `input`, then loops over that array and tests to see if that particular sequence has been seen before; if it has not been seen, it prints the value. It then rotates that sequence through all 13 positions, adding those values to a known-rotation associative array. I simplified the data in order to show the method; you can take the shell loop and adjust the input or output as needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
readarray -t input < input
declare -A rotations
for((i=0; i < ${#input[*]}; i++))
do
  x=${input[i]}
  [[ ${rotations[$x]:-0} -eq 0 ]] && printf "%s\n" "$x"
  for((r=0; r < 13; r++))
  do
    new=${x:r}${x:0:r}
    rotations[$new]=1
  done
done
```

Sample input data (copied from the Question, then simplified):

```
0010111220121
0020222110212
0101112201210
0111220121001
0121001011122
0202221102120
0212002022211
0222110212002
1001011122012
1011122012100
1021200202221
1102120020222
1112201210010
1122012100101
1200202221102
1210010111220
1220121001011
2002022211021
```

Sample output:

```
0010111220121
0020222110212
```

Comment: Hello thank you for this very useful solution  , but i will keep my mathematica wrapper because size of sequence are not limited to 13 , it may vary in a same array from 2 to 121 in length . nonetheless this solution give me some useful clue to find a correct system .

Comment: You were right it is safe to adjust the r variable to a maximum value ( here i arbitrary chosen 200) to handle sequence of long size .it works

Comment: Or change 13 to ${#x} to dynamically loop to the length of each string